# Button size and color in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new in SwiftUI and also iOS development.

I tried to create 2 buttons, but I can't change the color of background or size.

it looks like this:

[image]

below is the code:

```
        HStack {
            Button( action: {
                print("click")
            }){
                Text("Login")
                    .foregroundColor(.purple)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.purple, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
            }
            Button( action: {
                print("click")
            }){
                Text("Register")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
                            
                    )
                
            }
        }
```

I am looking to get a button which is almost using half of the screen with margin of 10px on each side. The goal is to have the 2 buttons to cover almost the width of the display. Also I try to make it thinner. the distance between the border on top and bottom is too big, I would like it close to the text when the one on left and right must be wider.

Also I can't figure out how to change the button background color to black

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

=> Long story in short

May someone found it handy.

```
struct test: View {
let roundRect = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Button( action: {
            print("click")
        }){
            Text("Login")
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.4, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                .background(roundRect.fill(Color.orange))
                .overlay(roundRect.stroke())
        }
    }.foregroundColor(.purple)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `ButtonStyle` which you can fully customise and *reuse*:

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(10) // *make it thinner*
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) // expand horizontally 
            .foregroundColor(.purple)
            .background(
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(Color.purple, lineWidth: 1)
                    .background(Color.black) // *change the button background color to black*
                    .cornerRadius(20)
            )
            .padding(.horizontal, 10) // *margin of 10px on each side*
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.7 : 1)
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Login") {
                print("click")
            }
            .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
            Button("Register") {
                print("click")
            }
            .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most **important** thing that we can remember for us is when we are facing with situation that we are not sure about size, then use shapes to fill all available space and then limit them as you want, like I did in code, you can change the numbers to your design.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        HStack {
            
            Button( action: {
                
                print("Login Button")
                
            }){
                
                CustomButtonView(stringOfButton: "Login")
                
                
            }
            
            Button( action: {
                
                print("Register Button")
                
            }){
                
                CustomButtonView(stringOfButton: "Register")

            }
            
        }
        .padding()

        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct CustomButtonView: View {
    
    var stringOfButton: String
    

    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.black)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .stroke(Color.purple, lineWidth: 1)
                )
                .frame(height: 50, alignment: .center)
            
            Text(stringOfButton)
                .foregroundColor(.purple)
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

[image]